# Right navigation drawer in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation

I have implemented left navigation drawer using [this](https://github.com/krunal3kapadiya/react-navigation-custom-drawer) library. I need the navigation drawer in both (left and right) side.

**How can I create navigation drawer in both side?**

I have achieved this, here is the gif for it. [image].